# Show confirm messagebox on RadioButton list click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a radio button list (radio1,radio2,radio3) inside a Div.

When I click one of the radio, I hide and show a div which contains some checkboxes.
OnClick of the radio button I need to make sure I uncheck the already checked checkboxes.

So at a time a user can select one radio button and he can check the checkboxes related to the Div.
If the user selects radio2 then I should be able to uncheck all the content of the the other divs, except radio2.

I am able to achieve the above senario, with the below code.

But the problem is:
  - Suppose if radio2 is already checked and if the user clicks again on radio2: its unchecking the content of radio2. which I need to stop.

And I want to add a confirm message box (ok and cancel buttons), on each click it will warn the user. if the user clicks on cancel then it should keep the state as existing.

I have written a function for this, but its not working.

```
<div id="radioDiv">                    
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioList" runat="server" >
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" >NewYork</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" >London</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" >Paris</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div> 

<div id=nyDiv>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="nycheck1" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="nycheck2" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
</div>
<div id=ldDiv>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ldcheck1" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ldcheck2" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
</div>
<div id=paDiv>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="pacheck1" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="pacheck2" runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
</div>



function showCity(city) {
    jQuery('#radioDiv input').click(function () {
        //Show confirm message  
        showConfirmMessage('#radioDiv input:radio:checked');

        //Show Hide div
        if (jQuery('#radioDiv input:radio:checked').val() == ) {
            jQuery('#nyDiv').css("display", "block");
            jQuery('#ldDiv').css("display", "none");
            jQuery('#paDiv').css("display", "none");
        }
    }
}


function showConfirmMessage(radioDiv) {
    if (jQuery(radioDiv).val() == 0) {
        var result = confirm("Moving to another city will result in loosing all the existing changes.");
        if (result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're saying that when a radio is clicked and its corresponding div of check boxes appears, clicking that radio again would reset those checkbox's back to default.

If that is the case, then couldn't you add a class of "active" or something similar to mark the radio button as being in use after it is first clicked. Then when you click on it again check if that radio button has a class of active before resetting the the checkboxes.

So basically, just disable the radio button if the user try's to click it again, and re-enable it when they click on another radio button.

Excuse the psuedo-code, im at a bus stop. I'll give an example when im home.

EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/1L34rm96/8/

Just a simplified version of what I think you're doing. Shouldnt be too hard to convert it over. I left plenty of comments in the fiddle.

HTML

```
<form>
<input class="radios" type="radio" name="r" value="male">r1</input>
<br/>
<input class="radios" type="radio" name="r" value="female">r2</input>
<br/>
<input class="radios" type="radio" name="r" value="male">r3</input>
<br/>
</form>
<div id="checkBoxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike</input>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a car</input>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a wife</input>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">I have a stupid fat dog</input>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".radios").on("click", function () {
    if (!$this.hasClass("active")) {
        $(".radios").removeClass("active");
        $this.addClass("active");
        $("#checkBoxes").show();
        alert("I'm not selected, get me check boxes!");
    }else{ 
        //the checkboxes for that radio are currently being displayed
        //don't reset your checkboxes!
        //whatever else needs to be here
        alert("I'm already selected, do nothing!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that is what exactly I am looking for. If you can give example will appreciate.